# .htaccess avoid only one file from browser catch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have below in my htaccess file.

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A29030400
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A29030400
ExpiresByType image/png A29030400
ExpiresByType text/css A29030400
ExpiresByType text/javascript A29030400
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A29030400
```

Everything works perfectly fine. Now i have one config file which is **config.js** which i dont want browser to catch.

Does anybody have idea how i can avoid catching only one file using htaccess.

I have blow situation i am using filesmatch..if file is lang.js/config.js then set expiry to 1 day otherwise whatever specified in above.. is below setting correct or something else i need to do.

```
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On

   ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 months"
   ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 6 months"
   ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 months"
   ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 6 months"
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2 years"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2 years"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2 years"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2 years"
   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2 years"
# Do not cache dynamically generated pages.
   ExpiresByType text/html A1
# Cache all files for a month after access (A).
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 21 days"

 # Dont catch below files

   <FilesMatch "^(lang|config)\.js$">
       ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
   </FilesMatch>
 </IfModule>
```

thank you in advance.
Regards,
Mona

Comment: i've edited my answer again, let me know if that works

Comment: You are great Foibs.. thank you so much for your help.. i recently started learning this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files) directive

```
<Files "config.js">
  #your desired config here
</Files>
```

For directory matching you can also use [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) directive

```
<Directory "/dir/with/different/config">
  #your desired config here
</Directory>
```

EDIT AFTER QUESTION EDIT:

ExpiresDefault is used if there is not ExpiresByType for that content type. Assuming that `config.js` and `lang.js` are sent as `application/javascript`, you need to the change the last lines like this, to overwrite settings from the previous lines

```
<FilesMatch "^(lang|config)\.js$">
   ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 day"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Ho Foibs.. one last doubt.. can i use <file> inside IfModule mod_expires.c directive.. in my situation if file is config.js then dont catch it..

Comment: Yes you can. Actually, you should put everything inside the same IfModule directive. Also, if necessary, you can place `<Files>` inside `<Directory>`